# Connected line plots depicting average of groups, split by category

Tags: plot, graph, line, stata, connect

I have data where there are many observations across two variables, say `rep78` and `headroom`.

I want to take the mean of a third variable, say `weight` within each `rep78`+`headroom` cell. For each `headroom` category, I separately want to plot (connected dot plot) these mean values with `rep78` on the x-axis. I suppose a more intuitive way to think of this is to replace `rep78` with `year` and `headroom` with `state`.

I have been able to get what I want with the code below:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
bys rep78 headroom: egen mean_w=mean(weight)
twoway  (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==1.5, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==2.0, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==2.5, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==3.0, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==3.5, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==4.0, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==4.5, connect(l)) ///
        (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom==5.0, connect(l)), ///
        legend(label(1 "1.5") label(2 "2.0") label(3 "2.5") ///
              label(4 "3.0") label(5 "3.5") label(6 "4.0") ///
              label(7 "4.5") label(8 "5.0"))
```

However, is there an easier (i.e. shorter) way to do this?

I am fine with simplifying any and all parts of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the MCVE!

You are correct. Here is one shorter solution to get the same graph, modulo small details you can tune too:

```
sepscatter mean_w rep78, sep(headroom) recast(connected) name(G2, replace)
```

using `sepscatter` from SSC, as announced [on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/3803-sepscatter-available-from-ssc). Further examples can be found using `sepscatter` as a search term on Statalist.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything complicated here.

The *community-contributed* command `sepscatter` is a nice wrapper but if code brevity is a concern you can also do the following without installing anything:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
bysort rep78 headroom: egen mean_w=mean(weight)

levelsof headroom, local(head)

foreach x of local head {
    local scatterlist `scatterlist' (scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom == `x', connect(l))
}

twoway `scatterlist'
```

To alleviate any precision concerns, one can use `float()` if the variable is not generated as double:

```
(scatter mean_w rep78 if headroom == float(`x'), connect(l))
```